# How to catch all incoming UDP packet with only IP/port source

Tags: networking, udp

I'm trying to catch every UDP packet coming from a device ( a camera), which is located on my local network.

The problem is the following:
- I know source IP/port and my computer IP, but when I receive the stream, the destination port is unknown.

I want something to bind UDP coming socket to every port, but this method does not exist.

My question is: Do you know how to catch every UDP packet coming from a source, with only source Port and source IP ( and my computer IP, of course).

Thank you

Comment: This is only possible if you can use a [pcap library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap). But this should be much simpler if you can get the camera to use a deterministic port. How does the camera actually select its destination port?

Comment: Thank's for your answer. I can't select destination port but only source port..

Comment: Well, then the only way to achieve this is to sniff all the packets on your interface using a pcap library and then recover the video stream from all packets coming from the camera. But I have the feeling that this not actually needed in any case and that you can relax your requirements (of not being able to specify a destination port). Are you trying to intercept traffic that is destined for another application on your PC? this is the only explanation that I can find for your requirement...

Comment: I want to know the exact amount of data ( in bytes) coming from my camera. The problem is that when you read camera's stream with openCV, you're not able to know the quantity of data that is coming before decoding the stream. That's why I want to sniff every UDP coming packet, before decoding, in order to know the exact throughput

Comment: Maybe  you don'k need to make your custom program then. Why not simply using Wireshark ? Based on your requirement , that should do the job easily

Answer (score 1):

Your camera should have a **destination** IP address and UDP port in its configuration.

That is, the camera will send UDP datagrams to **that specific IP address and port**. It may also support **broadcast / multicast** (sending to all the nodes in your subnet), in which case one or more bits of the destination address are set to 1 (e.g. 192.168.1.255 which is the broadcast address for the network 192.168.1.x).

You should ensure these conditions are met:

1. The listening socket is bound to the **correct network** interface
2. The UDP port is **the same** as the one you set in your camera settings
3. The destination IP address set in your camera is **the same** as your PC

Comment: Thank you for the answer! 
The device is an IP camera. I open/decode and read stream using openCV / and display it on HMI with Qt.
The camera is sending data with a specific IP/port but when I receive it on my computer, the destination port is random. That's why I can't bind my socket to my IP/destination port: I don't know the port number.
This is the wireshark line of a UDP packet:
192.168.1.10 (Camera's IP/static) / 50000 (Camera's port/static) ----> 192.168.1.25 (Computer's IP/static) / 26485 (Computer's port/random)

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear. How do you receive / decode the stream if you can't bind the socket? Do you have multiple programs that need to receive the UDP stream at the same time?

Comment: Using opencv, it's really simple.
You just have to give camera's IP and then, the stream is opened,readed and decoded. 
Yes, i definitively have 2 programs that need to receive the UDP stream: opencv ( high level lib, so we don't know exactly how does it work but it use ffmpeg to read packet) and my own "sniffer", in order to measure throughput

Comment: I see, then you should just bind the UDP socket of your program with exactly the same parameters you use on the OpenCV side, provided that the OpenCV side is bound with the SO_REUSEADDR mode. If you update your question including the OpenCV code and how you open the stream, we may suggest other alternatives